# In R, how to include title when using "plot(region)"?

Tags: r, mapping

R's "plot(region)" command does not print out any title--how can I correct this?  The "main" command does not work in either of the "plot" lines below.

```
library(OpenStreetMap)
library(rJava)
library(rgdal)
library(UScensus2000)

data(louisiana.tract)
m65 = na.omit(louisiana.tract@data$age.65.up)
a65 = cut(m65,breaks=c(min(m65),500,750,1000,3500))  
levels(a65) = c("0-500","501-750","751-1000",">1000")

la <- spTransform(louisiana.tract,osm())
lat <- c(30.4, 29.5)
lon <- c(-90.7, -89.5)
region <- openmap(c(lat[1],lon[1]),c(lat[2],lon[2]),zoom=10,'osm')
windows()
plot(region, main = "New Orleans area: \n residents 65 and over by ZIP")
plot(la,add=TRUE,col=c("light cyan","light blue", "cyan" ,"dodgerblue"))
  legend(locator(1), cex=.8, levels(a65), fill=c("light cyan","light blue", "cyan" ,"dodgerblue") )
```

Comment: The UScensus2000 package is huge. People should be prepared for a long wait.

Comment: The fact that it runs on 2 PC and not on a third implies you have not offered enough information. This is in effect a poll or the readership to see if anyone else has a broken installation as well. So maybe you should provide system details with sessionInfo() on a working and a non-working system? (Or split these into two separate questions with appropriate OS tags.)

Comment: It's possible that the `plot` method for whatever class the output of `openmap` is forgot to allow the argument "main" .  You'll have to look at the `plot.[whateverclass]` code in the package.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a plot routine is lacking the "main" argument, you can simply place a "main"-title with:

```
title( main = "New Orleans area: \n residents 65 and over by ZIP")
```